# Safari iOS gyroscope cursor

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, webkit

Given

```
    var pointer = document.getElementById("pointer");

    window.ondeviceorientation = function(event) {
      ax = Math.round(event.alpha);
      ay = Math.round(event.beta);
      az = Math.round(event.gamma);
    }

    setInterval(function() {

            // ???

            pointer.style.left = x + "px"; 
            pointer.style.top = y + "px"; 
    }, 25);
```

what is the right function to move the 'pointer' so it can move accordingly to the iphone orientation?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking how to position an element at a given top/left coordinate using CSS? Or are you asking how to get those top/left values?

Comment: Um, those values are angles not accelearations?

Comment: yes, the point is i'm trying to make a prototype of a mouse, or imagine a pointer controlled by the iphone...i'm wondering if also compass should be involved for orientation left/right